# I want to find the version of a .class file

Tags: java

Is there any way to find the java version from a compiled java .class file ?

Comment: You can use the bcel library for that

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for this on the command line (for a class called MyClass):

> javap -verbose MyClass

You want the major version from the results. Here are some example values:

```
Java 1.2 uses major version 46
Java 1.3 uses major version 47
Java 1.4 uses major version 48
Java 5 uses major version 49
Java 6 uses major version 50
Java 7 uses major version 51
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get the version of your class using:

```
javap -verbose help
```

The [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javap.html) comes with jdk and the `verbose` tells the version.

```
> javap -verbose help
Compiled from "help.java"
public class help
  SourceFile: "help.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 46
```